# Objects of an inner class in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes

An object of an inner class in Java has a special *handle* to the outer object i.e. `this$0`. However, the outer object has not the same access to the inner object.

This allows the inner object to have access to outer variables or methods even if they are private.

Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: "*This allows the inner object to have access to outer variables or methods even if they are private*"  Try it and find out

Comment: I have tried it. The answer is yes because this special handle? This is what I am wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> When an inner class (whose declaration does not occur in a static
>   context) refers to an instance variable that is a member of a
>   lexically enclosing class, the variable of the corresponding lexically
>   enclosing instance is used.

This means that, YES, instance variables of the enclosing classes are accessible to inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

`private` limits access only to the scope of the *compilation unit* (the source file), so all classes in the same file can access each other's private members, whether they be inner classes or not.

The only special thing about an inner class is (as you say) that each instance of it refers to a particular instance of the outer class, but if it somehow obtains a reference to another outer class instance (e.g. as a parameter to a method call), it can access the other instance's members as well. Similarly, if an instance of an outer class is somehow given a reference to an instance of an inner class, it can access its members, even if it doesn't "own" that particular inner class instance.

Comment: Thank you. This is a subtle detail I've never thought of.